# What are "C++ Variables" in Visual Studio's "Display Items"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, ide

In Visual Studio, you can customize the font and color of any display items such as C++ keywords, C++ parameters, C++ local variables, function names, macros, etc. You can do so through selecting the menu "Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors".

In the setting dialog, I am confused by two "Display Items": "C++ Local Variables" and "C++ Variables".

"C++ Local Variables" is easy to understand. Say:

```
void f()
{
    int this_is_a_Cpp_Local_Variable;
}
```

I can set the C++ Local Variables to any font and color as I like.

However, I cannot understand what the "C++ Variables" are. I have tested and proved they are not global variables, no matter the global variable is a fundamental type or a user-defined type.

My question is: What's a "C++ Variable" in Visual Studio's "Display Items"?

**Updates:**

My test code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int n;
};

A a;

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        int v;
        a.n
    }
};

void f(A a)
{
    a.n;
}

int main()
{
    int v;
    A a;
}
```

The vssettings:

```
<UserSettings>
    <ApplicationIdentity version="11.0"/>
    <ToolsOptions>
        <ToolsOptionsCategory name="Environment" RegisteredName="Environment"/>
    </ToolsOptions>
    <Category name="Environment_Group" RegisteredName="Environment_Group">
        <Category name="Environment_FontsAndColors" Category="{1EDA5DD4-927A-43a7-810E-7FD247D0DA1D}" Package="{DA9FB551-C724-11d0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}" RegisteredName="Environment_FontsAndColors" PackageName="Visual Studio Environment Package">
            <PropertyValue name="Version">2</PropertyValue>
            <FontsAndColors Version="2.0">
                <Categories>
                    <Category GUID="{58E96763-1D3B-4E05-B6BA-FF7115FD0B7B}" FontName="Fixedsys Excelsior 3.01" FontSize="12" CharSet="1" FontIsDefault="No">
                        <Items/>
                    </Category>
                    <Category GUID="{75A05685-00A8-4DED-BAE5-E7A50BFA929A}" FontName="Fixedsys Excelsior 3.01" FontSize="12" CharSet="1" FontIsDefault="No">
                        <Items>
                            <Item Name="Literal" Foreground="0x000000FF" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="String" Foreground="0x000000FF" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppMacroSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x000000FF" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppEnumSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x000000FF" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppGlobalVariableSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x000000FF" Background="0x00008000" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppLocalVariableSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x00000080" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppParameterSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x00000000" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppTypeSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x00FF0000" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppRefTypeSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x00FF0000" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppValueTypeSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x00FF0000" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppFunctionSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x00000080" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppMemberFunctionSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x00000080" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppStaticMemberFunctionSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x00000080" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppClassTemplateSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x00FF0000" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppGenericTypeSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x00FF0000" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppFunctionTemplateSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x00000080" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppNamespaceSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x000000FF" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="CppLabelSemanticTokenFormat" Foreground="0x000000FF" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="VA X Brace Matching" Foreground="0x02000000" Background="0x02000000" BoldFont="Yes"/>
                        </Items>
                    </Category>
                    <Category GUID="{B36B0228-DBAD-4DB0-B9C7-2AD3E572010F}" FontName="Microsoft YaHei" FontSize="9" CharSet="1" FontIsDefault="No">
                        <Items>
                            <Item Name="Different content" Foreground="0x000014E5" Background="0x00FFFFFF" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="Identical content" Foreground="0x00000000" Background="0x00FFFFFF" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="Source Only" Foreground="0x00000000" Background="0x00FFFFFF" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="Target Only" Foreground="0x00000000" Background="0x00FFFFFF" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="Not Downloaded" Foreground="0x006D6D6D" Background="0x00FFFFFF" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="Even Row Items" Foreground="0x00000000" Background="0x00FFFFFF" BoldFont="No"/>
                            <Item Name="Odd Row Items" Foreground="0x00000000" Background="0x00FFFFFF" BoldFont="No"/>
                        </Items>
                    </Category>
                    <Category GUID="{E0187991-B458-4F7E-8CA9-42C9A573B56C}" FontName="Fixedsys Excelsior 3.01" FontSize="12" CharSet="1" FontIsDefault="No">
                        <Items>
                            <Item Name="String" Foreground="0x000000FF" Background="0x01000001" BoldFont="No"/>
                        </Items>
                    </Category>
                    <Category GUID="{FF349800-EA43-46C1-8C98-878E78F46501}" FontName="Fixedsys Excelsior 3.01" FontSize="12" CharSet="1" FontIsDefault="No">
                        <Items/>
                    </Category>
                </Categories>
            </FontsAndColors>
        </Category>
    </Category>
</UserSettings>
```

Comment: Are they variables of other classes?  For example, Class `A` has a public int variable `someInt`, and in class `B`, you refer to `someObjectOfA.someInt`?  I'm not sitting in front of VS right now so I can't play around with it myself.

Comment: @nhgrif, No. I have tested and the result showed your guess is not correct.

Comment: When you checked Global Variables, where did you check them?  Did you declare a Global Variable then see what color it showed up as within functions?  So like, `function A` makes use of two variables, variable `foo` which is `Global` and declared outside of `function A` and variable `bar` which is local and declared within `function B`.  Do they show up differently there?

Comment: @nhgrif, no any effects by changing the setting of "C++ Variables"

Comment: @xmllmx Why did you tag this 2010 when you claim to be using 2013 RC?

Comment: @RedX, I have deleted that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see it highlights the different types of variables on your C++ projects. This is Visual Studio 2012 with a custom color scheme.

```
blue := local
green := global variable
```

[image: Imgur]

So this is your code highlighted with my settings:

[image: Imgur]

This is your colorsettings with background color red for local variables

[image: Imgur]

Comment: "C++ Variables" are not "C++ Global Variables" in terms of VS's "Display Items"

Comment: C++ Variables are all non-local variable as you can see from the highlight i just took from my own VS IDE.

Comment: @xmllmx can you please post the file you are using to test it, along with a copy if the vssettings export file with the color settings?

Comment: Please review my post. I put them there.

Comment: @xmllmx You can see from the update, highlighting does highlight local and non-local variables properly in 2012. If it is not doing that in 2013 then you should file a bug.